# Adding __init__.py in eclipse python interpreter' libraries

Tags: qgis

I am trying to Make eclipse understand the API in of QGIS. the `__init__.py` module is available in this address: `C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py` but when I try to add it in python interpreter.libraries tab, it can not be found and I just can add the following address: `C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\qgis\python\qgis` I want to know is it right or I should find `__init__.py` to add it in Libraries?

Comment: I looked into this some time ago. Not sure if the guide is up to date though http://blog.vitu.ch/01082013-1452/develop-qgis-python-plugins-using-eclipse-pydev